# Calling a method in a static library

Tags: c++, c, static-libraries, standard-library

I'm trying to write a C standard library from scratch on OSX with gcc. When I try to include a header file from my library in my test program, I get the error that it isn't defined. I try to use the -nostdlib flag but I still can't include my file.

My test program:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <bool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <io.h>

int main(){
    int x = sin(0.5);
    int y = pow(2,3);
    int z = abs(12);
    myiofunction(7);
    exit(0);
}
```

math.h,bool.h,ctype.h,string.h, and io.h are defined in my library. What am I doing incorrectly?

EDIT:
The error message that I am getting is:

```
helloTest.c:10:10: fatal error: 'bool.h' file not found
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: @nneonneo I added it to the question.

Comment: ...did you use `-I` to specify the right include paths?

Comment: @nneonneo I did when compiling the library

Comment: Yes, but did you do it *when compiling your program*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Header files aren't compiled into a static library. They have to be available to both library and program.

Therefore, when compiling your program, make sure to specify the `-I` options to let the compiler find your library's header files.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to do that! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In order for it to use your own standard library as well, you have to use the `-I` option to include your library:

```
gcc -nostdlib -I/path/to/my/headers/ ...
```

So if the headers for those files were located in `./include`, you'd compile with:

```
gcc -nostdlib -I./include/ ....
```

Of course you need to provide the object code for these functions at some point. Then you can link them all together using `ld` with `-lgcc` to resolve any internal GCC subroutines.
GCC Linking Options: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to write :

`#include "bool.h"`

Check that out:
 [Include Syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html#Include-Syntax)

Comment: I just get the same error `helloTest.c:10:10: fatal error: 'bool.h' file not found`

Comment: Then there can be possibility is that you placed that header file somewhere else or misspell the header.

Answer (score 0):

If you use  it won't work anyway. You have to typed as "bool.h"

and the other thing is -l option.
Check it out : https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

If you specifiy the default location : -R [PATH]

Answer (score 0):

The library to include is

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the case, since OP mentioned [...] `math.h,bool.h,ctype.h,string.h, and io.h are defined in my library. What am I doing incorrectly?` [...]